# Change where Xcode dumps coverage data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, code-coverage

Is there any way to change where Xcode (4.4.1) dumps the resulting code coverage data files after a unit test run?

I currently have to find them in:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RoadRunner-dvrnbrtwppxktzfuqspojzlgrodg/Build/Intermediates/RoadRunner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RoadRunnerIPadTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the global derived data location from Xcode's Locations preferences. Choosing File > Project Settings lets you change the derived data location for a single project. You could also change the Build Products Path and Intermediate Build Files Path build settings to change the location for the unit test target while leaving your other targets unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Organizor->Select Projects-> Delete Drived Data

Comment: I want to change the output directory, not delete the data.